# Blender renders, but the saved output - and render window - is empty; can't render more than HD

Tags: cycles-render-engine, saving, empty

It's a simple scene, two spaceships, an animated camera, sun and 18k HDRI from TrueSpace (blender addon); 580k polys. It was working great before, but during a long render - Cycles GPU - to RGBA 16bit .PNG the last 340 frames out of 600 were empty. The other 260 frames were as expected - one spaceship without the BG (set to transparent in FILM). I was rendering at 3840x2160, GPU, 500 samples, Open Image denoising ON.
COMPUTER SPECS: AMD5950, 128GB RAM, Nvidia 3090, 24GB VRAM.

What I've done so far, restart, reboot, new project with collections appended.

I CAN render correctly at HD using cycles, but any pixel dimension higher hangs, so no to 4K. But I WAS able to previously. I CAN render 4k with EEVEE, and the saved files are OK. When rendering with cycles to 4k - just a single frame (F12), it renders to 4 tiles - 2 big squares and 2 skinny strips, it seems to get hung up on the last 4 samples of the last tile and hangs there.

It all worked fine yesterday, but something about that 600 frame render killed it.